# Carte Server unable to connect to repository in Slave Server

Tags: rest, api, kettle, pdi

I'm setting up a new Carte Server for running Pentaho schedule job. I can run job remotely using Kettle Spoon. I'm using MySQL as repository.

But when I run Job using REST API follow document from
[Pentaho](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0R0/070/020/020/030)

When I run job with 
/kettle/runJob/?job=Job_test_2. Server return error with message:

```
    <webresult>
  <result>ERROR</result>
  <message>Unexpected error running job: 
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
Unable to connect to repository in Slave Server Config: null

    at org.pentaho.di.www.RunJobServlet.doGet(RunJobServlet.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</message>
  <id/>
</webresult>
```

I google for this problem. They guide that copy the .kettle folder to home directory. But it not work. Any one can explains this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find myself the problem that Carte doesn't read config from .kettle folder. It read connection and repository from config-master.xml when you run Carte server with command ./carte.sh config-master.xml. So I can easily add the connection copy from .kettle folder and add repository with username and password to run the job. Hope this help.